# Cannot vertical align absolute span

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm trying to positioned the navigation in the middle position of the container, but I haven't can, yet. I'm using `span` for navigation.

I have positioned the parent containers as relative how is recommended and then assign position to `span` using top, right and left.

```css
img{
    max-width:600px;
}
.slider{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    width: 100%;
}
.slider ul{
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.slider ul li{
    margin-right: -4px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slider ul li.active{
    display: list-item;
}

/*Navegacion*/
.flechas-nav .anterior, .flechas-nav .siguiente{
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.flechas-nav .anterior {
 
 top: 50%;
}

.flechas-nav .siguiente{
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
}
.flechas-nav span {
 height: 100%;
 width: 10%;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 900;
}

.slider:hover .flechas-nav span {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slider-contenedor">
                <li class="slide active">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Khgz4Qd.jpg" alt="">
                    
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dc3XS7w.jpg" alt="">
                    
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/aVzLCnM.jpg" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
   <div class="flechas-nav">
    <span class="anterior">Left</span>
    <span class="siguiente">Right</span>
   </div>
   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I put demo on jsfiddle.

How can I position vertical middle this `span`?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/17ow14kf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your CSS. For one, when using `position:absolute` it removes the element out of the flow of the document. Both your image and text are being positioned absolute. so there is no height or width being registering in your document. That's why `top: 50%` isn't working. So start by removing the positioning from `.slider ul li`

```
.slider ul li{
   margin-right: -4px;
   width: 100%;
   /*position: absolute;*/ //remove
   display: none;
   /*top: 0;*/ //not needed anymore
   /*left: 0;*/ //not needed anymore
}
```

Now `top:50%` will work and the words "left" and "right" will seemingly be centered. There's a few more things:

Next, your `div` containers are `display: block` by default so they take the width of the document. Since your image is not `width:100%` the container is too large and the word "right" will disappear because the image isn't wide enough. (check out your demo and user4429928's answer - make the screen large and "right" will seem to disappear). You can set the container to `display: inline-block` so it wraps the image:

```
.container{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Now, I would remove the absolute positioning from `.anterior` and `.siguiente` and add the positioning to the parent instead and float the children:

```
.flechas-nav{
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   color: #FFF;
   transform: translateY(-50%); //read note below about this
}

.flechas-nav .anterior {
   float: left;
}
```

.flechas-nav .siguiente{
       float: right;
       text-align: right;
   }

Calling `top:50%` does not actually center an element, it positions it 50% from it's top. In this case becasue your text has very little height, it looks ok, but if you added `height: 200px` or something, you would see that it's not actually centered. To correct this you can use:

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Now your content is centered and within its parent. And to fix the image rotating issue you can set the image thats fading out to `absolute` and the one that comes in to `static`:

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/79rvgbxt/1/)

Comment: Thanks! for your help... But I need overlap all <li> because I'm making a slider... Now nav can be center but when I change the slider the slide appear bellow instead of behind... See here... http://jsfiddle.net/79rvgbxt/

Comment: See when you click on Right or Left the next image appear bellow and then move to top... The images are not one over another (not overlap)... If you remove display: none form .slider ul li you can see that image are one bellow another... I was using absoltue before for position overlap...

Answer (score 0):

try the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/17ow14kf/2/

```
img{
    max-width:600px;
}

.slider {
    height: 210px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.slider ul{
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.slider ul li{
    margin-right: -4px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slider ul li.active{
    display: list-item;
}

/*Navegacion*/
.flechas-nav .anterior, .flechas-nav .siguiente{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flechas-nav .anterior {

    top: 50%;
}

.flechas-nav .siguiente{
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.flechas-nav span {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 900;
}

.slider:hover .flechas-nav span {
    opacity: 1;
}
.flechas-nav {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%; color:#fff;
}
.flechas-nav .anterior {
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```